# Set variable font sizes in DIALOGEX Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to have variable font sizes in my visual c++ (6.0 Standard Edition) dialog box.

Here is my code.
How can I implement it?

```
IDD_HPLED_FORM DIALOGEX 0, 0, 329, 225
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_CHILD | WS_CAPTION
//FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
FONT 14, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN

    EDITTEXT        IDC_VF,32,44,35,20,ES_RIGHT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | 
                    ES_READONLY
    RTEXT           "Vf:",IDC_STATIC,16,44,11,8
    EDITTEXT        IDC_VR,32,4,35,20,ES_RIGHT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | 
                    ES_READONLY
    RTEXT           "Vr:",IDC_STATIC,16,4,11,8

END
```

how can I have Vr and Vf in different font sizes?

Comment: I don't think you can do it via dialog template. You can set up fonts programmatically, usually in `WM_INITDIALOG` handler. See `WM_SETFONT`.

Comment: do you know anyway I can implement that in my code?

Comment: What Igor said. I can share some code if you like....

Answer (score 1):

Add member variables of your dialog class.

```
CFont       Font;
LOGFONT     FontData;
```

Create font and set that on your edit box at OnInitDialg().

```
BOOL CMy...Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    ...

    HFONT hFont = (HFONT)::GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
    ::GetObject(hFont, sizeof(LOGFONT), &FontData);
    Font.CreateFontIndirect(&FontData);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_VF)->SetFont(&font, TRUE);
}
```

And then you shoud call Font.DeleteObject() when your dialog closed.

```
Font.DeleteObject();
```